# NSData.FromStream() - filesize doubles and files are corrupted

Tags: xamarin.ios

I'm trying to encrypt a file on the fly using the following code:

```
NSError oError = null;
using ( FileStream oStream = File.Open ( sSourcePathAndFile, FileMode.Open ) )
{
  NSData oData = NSData.FromStream ( oStream );
  // Save and encrypt.
  oData.Save ( sDestPathAndFile, NSDataWritingOptions.FileProtectionAlways, out oError );
}
```

There is no error but all the saved files have approximately doubled in size and are corrupt. Even if I set the writing options "FileProtectionNone", which should not change the file at all, I get the same results.

Any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't something like this help? Haven't tried this on monotouch but AFAIK needed namespaces are included on the mtouch stack

```
using System.Security;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

// Function to Generate a 64 bits Key.
      static string GenerateKey() 
      {
         // Create an instance of Symetric Algorithm. Key and IV is generated automatically.
         DESCryptoServiceProvider desCrypto =(DESCryptoServiceProvider)DESCryptoServiceProvider.Create();

         // Use the Automatically generated key for Encryption. 
         return ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(desCrypto.Key);
      }

      static void EncryptFile(string sInputFilename,
         string sOutputFilename, 
         string sKey) 
      {
         FileStream fsInput = new FileStream(sInputFilename, 
            FileMode.Open, 
            FileAccess.Read);

         FileStream fsEncrypted = new FileStream(sOutputFilename, 
            FileMode.Create, 
            FileAccess.Write);
         DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
         DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
         DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
         ICryptoTransform desencrypt = DES.CreateEncryptor();
         CryptoStream cryptostream = new CryptoStream(fsEncrypted, 
            desencrypt, 
            CryptoStreamMode.Write); 

         byte[] bytearrayinput = new byte[fsInput.Length];
         fsInput.Read(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
         cryptostream.Write(bytearrayinput, 0, bytearrayinput.Length);
         cryptostream.Close();
         fsInput.Close();
         fsEncrypted.Close();
      }

      static void DecryptFile(string sInputFilename, 
         string sOutputFilename,
         string sKey)
      {
         DESCryptoServiceProvider DES = new DESCryptoServiceProvider();
         //A 64 bit key and IV is required for this provider.
         //Set secret key For DES algorithm.
         DES.Key = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);
         //Set initialization vector.
         DES.IV = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sKey);

         //Create a file stream to read the encrypted file back.
         FileStream fsread = new FileStream(sInputFilename, 
            FileMode.Open, 
            FileAccess.Read);
         //Create a DES decryptor from the DES instance.
         ICryptoTransform desdecrypt = DES.CreateDecryptor();
         //Create crypto stream set to read and do a 
         //DES decryption transform on incoming bytes.
         CryptoStream cryptostreamDecr = new CryptoStream(fsread, 
            desdecrypt,
            CryptoStreamMode.Read);
         //Print the contents of the decrypted file.
         StreamWriter fsDecrypted = new StreamWriter(sOutputFilename);
         fsDecrypted.Write(new StreamReader(cryptostreamDecr).ReadToEnd());
         fsDecrypted.Flush();
         fsDecrypted.Close();
      } 

      static void Main()
      {
         // Must be 64 bits, 8 bytes.
         // Distribute this key to the user who will decrypt this file.
         string sSecretKey;

         // Get the Key for the file to Encrypt.
         sSecretKey = GenerateKey();

         // For additional security Pin the key.
         GCHandle gch = GCHandle.Alloc( sSecretKey,GCHandleType.Pinned );

         // Encrypt the file.        
         EncryptFile(@"C:\MyData.txt", 
            @"C:\Encrypted.txt", 
            sSecretKey);

         // Decrypt the file.
         DecryptFile(@"C:\Encrypted.txt", 
            @"C:\Decrypted.txt", 
            sSecretKey);
      }
```

Comment: Maybe, but why would I if iOS and iPhone 3GS+ has build in hardware encryption?

Comment: hehehe yeah I know but as a workaround if you are on a rush of bringing the app to production :) I tested your code and yeah I got the files corrupted too, I guess we should file a bug

Comment: I tried once to file a bug at this weird Novell site and failed. If you have experience, please file a bug!

Comment: I managed to place a bug! I got a couple of 404s, was redirect to the weirdest pages but in the end I did it! YEAH! Let's see what happens.